# How set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in observable collection WPF - Windows phone 8.1

Tags: canvas, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with set into proper place on my phone screen this items. First i tried to binding Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top, but even set it like Canvas.Left="300" & Canvas.Top="200" still set in in left top position on screen.

```
 <ItemsControl Name="Canvas" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SensorsCollection}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Canvas.Left="300"
                      Canvas.Top="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontSize="30"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data template, put the Grid inside of a Canvas as well.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Canvas>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="300"
              Canvas.Top="200">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="30"/>

        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That's a terrible solution.  You'll have an extra canvas for each and every item in the control.  He should be setting the binding on the container, via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  I'd answer, but I'm not 100% sure of the wp8 equivalent, if different.